# optional command line argument for my script

Tags: python, cmd

I'm coding a script that either zips the hall folder or you can choose files with specific extension such as ".txt". I use sys.argv to pass the folder path and extension, if needed. However, when I pass the path the only thing I get is this error:

```
    fileEx = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I make the "file extension" command line optional?

My script:

```
  import zipfile, os, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    

    folder_path = sys.argv[1]
    fileEx = None
else:
    folder_path = sys.argv[1]
    fileEx = sys.argv[2]
def zipf(folder_path, fileEx=None):

    folder_path = os.path.abspath(folder_path)

    number = 1
    while True:
        zipfilename= os.path.basename(folder_path) + "_" + str(number) +'.zip'
        if not os.path.exists(zipfilename):
            break
        number = number + 1
    
    # creat the zip file
    print(f'creating {zipfilename}')
    backupZip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename, 'w')

    # walking through folders
    for foldername , subfolders , filenames in os.walk(folder_path):
        print(f'Adding files in {foldername}. . . ')
        #adding the folder
        backupZip.write(foldername)
        # adding all files in the folder to zipfile
        for filename in filenames:
            newBase = os.path.basename(folder_path) + '_'
            if filename.startswith(newBase) and filename.endswith('.zip'):
                continue
            if fileEx:
                if filename.endswith(fileEx):
                    os.chdir(foldername)
                    backupZip.write(os.path.join(foldername, filename))
            else:
                backupZip.write(os.path.join(foldername, filename))
    backupZip.close()

zipf("folder_path, fileEx")
```

Comment: If the length of `argv` is 2 then the highest index you can use is 1. Change the conditional to `if argv.len < 3` or `if argv.len <= 2` depending on your preferred style

Comment: You can also use `argparse`.

Comment: thank you so much it worked

Comment: I agree with @r0ei. If this is going to remain a simple script, indexing `argv` directly is fine and `argparse` would introduce unnecessary bloat the project. but for anything much larger, argparse adds a lot to the overall readability and maintanability